# how the use a xsl value as the ID for a onclick

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have the following code: (i use jquery)

```
<a href="javascript:" 
  onclick="document.getElementById('TEST').style.display = ( (document.getElementById('TEST').style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block' );">
  <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
</a>

<div id="TEST" style="display:none">
  <xsl:value-of select="@Announcement" />
</div>
```

This works fine. But I’m pulling multiple elements so the only shows of hide's the first announcement with is logical because that’s the first element with the ID:TEST

Now I would like you use  `<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />` for the elementbyid
but I can't just put that between the quotes. The following is not well formatted

```
<a href="javascript:" 
  onclick="document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />').style.display = ( (document.getElementById('TEST').style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block' );">
    <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
</a>
```

any tips on how to format this correct?

Comment: Your code doesn't have anything common with jQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `<xsl:attribute>` command **within** the element you wish the attribute to be placed...

```
<a href="javascript:">
  <xsl:attribute name="onclick">document.getElementById('<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />').style.display = ( (document.getElementById('TEST').style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block' );</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
</a>
```

**UPDATE** based on comments by OP...

As I said above, `<xsl:attribute` must be **WITHIN** the element you wish the attribute to be used... in fact it must be the **FIRST** command afterwards.

Instead of...

```
<xsl:attribute name="id"><div id="<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />"><xsl:value-of select="@Announcement" /></div></xsl:attribute>
```

You should have (formatted with newlines for viewing here)...

```
<div>
  <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Announcement"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked.

Do you alsno know you I can use the ID for the DIV?

    <div id="ID???"><xsl:value-of select="@Mededeling" /></DIV>

Comment: @user1537231 - sorry, I don't understand your question... are you asking if you can set the `id` attribute to the value of the `@Mededeling` attribute?  If so, just use the `<xsl:attribute>` command again

Comment: yes, Your code worked. I see a diffrent ID for every announcement...


but the ID should also be placed on de div where the actual announcement tekst wil be placed...


    <div id="" style="display:none">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Mededeling" />
    </div>

The ID nou is empty.
If i format it like your example above with the xsl:attribute i don't get it to work.

Comment: @user1537231 - if you found my answer helpful, [please upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) - if you also found the answer to be correct, [please mark as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @user1537231, it looks like you are simply displaying the `@Mededeling` *within* the DIV by using `<xsl:value-of`. Are you sure you are setting the attribute via `<xsl:attribute name="id">...`

Comment: This is what I now have:

<xsl:attribute name="id"><div id="<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />"><xsl:value-of select="@Announcement" /></div></xsl:attribute>

Comment: @Daan82, see my edited answer.  Have you changed your username to confuse me?!?  ;-)

Comment: Thanks freefaller
you saved my day and with your new explanation now I also understand what I’m doing.
I appreciate your help!

Thought it would be polite to post under my normal name instead of user 1537231 :-)

Comment: Not a problem @Daan82, and remember you can have multiple `<xsl:attribute>` commands if you need multiple attributes on a single element - as long as they're ALL straight after the element. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

**A more compact solution**:

```
<div id="{@ID}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Announcement"/>
</div>
```

Also, wirhin the `onclick` attribute use:

```
getElementById({@ID})
```